# Is the property of being a connected component local?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

More precisely, my question is as follows: Let $X$ be a qcqs scheme, $Z \subset X$ a closed subscheme and assume that there exists an open affine subscheme $U \subset X$ containing $Z$ such that $Z$ is a connected component of $U$. Does this imply that $Z$ is a connected component of $X$ ?

I do not know whether we need the algebro-geometric setup since this question only regards the underlying topological space of the scheme. Note that since $X$ is qcqs, every connected component is the intersection of its clopen supersets in $X$.

Comment: qcqs = quasi-compact quasi-separated. "quasi-compact" is just "compact" in the mainstream English terminology. quasi-separated is *not* just a condition on the underlying topological space, it involves the topology on $X\times X$, which is not determined by the topology on $X$.

Comment: If $Z$ is a connected component of $U$, then $Z$ is both open and closed in $U$.  Since $Z$ is open in $U$, and $U$ is open in $X$, also $Z$ is open in $X$.  Since you also assume that $Z$ is closed, the scheme $Z$ is both open and closed in $X$.  Since $Z$ is connected, the scheme $Z$ is a connected component of $X$.

Comment: @JasonStarr, so you used scheme-ness only to say that connected components are open, right?

Comment: @LSpice.  Now I am not so sure that this is actually true . . .

Comment: How does @JasonStarr's argument use scheme-ness at all? The argument looks sound for all topological spaces.

Comment: @AntonGeraschenko My argument is wrong, because "connected component" is not defined to be "nonempty open and closed subset that is connected".  It is defined to be "connected subset that is maximal with respect to set inclusion".

Comment: @JasonStarr, but connected components are always closed (because the closure of a connected set is connected), and a scheme has only finitely many connected components (by Noetherian-ness), so each is the complement of a closed set, hence open—right?

Comment: @LSpice If the scheme is Noetherian, that is true.  However, the OP does not specify that the scheme is Noetherian.

Comment: @JasonStarr: isn't "non-empty, connected, open, and closed" is the stronger condition? It ensures that the map $X\to \{0, 1\}$ sending $Z$ to 0 and its complement to 1 is continuous. The map restricts to a continuous map on any subset of $X$, which demonstrates that any strict superset of $Z$ is disconnected. [Edit: ah, but we don't have that $Z$ is open. gotcha.]

Comment: @LSpice: maximal connected subsets are not always closed; consider the deleted comb space, which is connected, but has two maximal connected subsets.

Comment: @AntonGeraschenko, I'm afraid that I don't understand some definition.  I don't know what the deleted comb space is, but if a large space is connected, then surely no proper subset of it can be *maximal* connected?

Comment: @LSpice: whoops, of course you're right.

Comment: @YCor: isn't a scheme quasi-separated if and only if the intersection of quasi-compact opens is quasi-compact?

Comment: The scheme $X$ may indeed not be Noetherian, thus the connected components are not open in general. I added the qcqs condition so that quasi-components and connected components are the same, but I do not know whether this condition is needed.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don't know, if I knew it I wouldn't have state my previous comment this way. Do you mean finite intersections?

Comment: @YCor: I meant binary intersections. (I thought that this was true, but didn't have time to look it up at the time of writing.)

Comment: This is not true for arbitrary qcqs topological spaces, at least (qcqs = has a basis of quasi-compact opens that is closed under finite intersections). Take U any qcqs disconnected space and let X = U ∪ {p} where U is open and the only open containing p is X. Then X is qcqs and connected, but U is not connected.

Comment: @Marc Hoyois: The example you gave is not a counterexample, since $Z$ is supposed to be closed in $X$. But in your setup the only closed set contained in U is the empty set.

Comment: You're right! If you add the complement of a non-isolated point of U as an open set, this would be a counterexample but probably not qcqs anymore.

Comment: I don not understand. I assume you want to take Z = {your non-isolated point}, but this will in general not be a connected component of U.

Comment: Sorry, in my head U was totally disconnected, so points are connected components.